# EthosConnect gets stuck in the "loading" status

Tags: sui

I am using [EthosConnect](https://docs.ethoswallet.xyz/) in my nextjs app. I was able to connect to the [Sui wallet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sui-wallet/opcgpfmipidbgpenhmajoajpbobppdil) however after I refreshed the page it show the following errors

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Error fetching owned object: Error: RPC Error: Method not found for address 

Call Stack
JsonRpcProvider.eval
node_modules/@mysten/sui.js/dist/index.mjs (3554:0)
Generator.throw
<anonymous>
rejected
node_modules/@mysten/sui.js/dist/index.mjs (52:0)
```

Below is my nextjs page

```
export default function HomePage() {
  const { status, wallet } = ethos.useWallet();

  return (
    <EthosConnectProvider
      dappName='Joed'
      connectMessage='Your connect message goes here!'
      ethosConfiguration={{
        hideEmailSignIn: false, // defaults to false,
      }}
    >
      <Layout>
        <Seo />

        <main>
          <section className='bg-white'>
            <div>
              Status: {status}, address {wallet?.address}
            </div>
            <SignInButton> Connect Wallet </SignInButton>
          </section>
        </main>
      </Layout>
    </EthosConnectProvider>
  );
}
```

[image]